# Setting a JTextfield focused from start

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, barcode-scanner

Making a project for school that involves scanning something from my "start frame" that looks like this --> http://i.gyazo.com/21ed444ad98b441e95c69901eceaef00.png

[image]

the textfield in the left bottom corner is where your scanned ID goes. to make it look cleaner i want to set it focused from start and then invisible. (does this even work?) so you can just scan without seeing numbers appear on the screen.

But setting the focus does not work for me. I've tried all these methodes

```
    txtKlantID.grabFocus();
    txtKlantID.requestFocus();
    txtKlantID.requestFocusInWindow();
```

txtKlantID being the name of the textfield.

thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Please post a link to the image itself, not the page that holds it. 2) Please create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better understand your current problem.

Comment: I cant, because i need 10 reputation for it to work

Comment: You can't post an image, but you can post a link to an image. You've posted a link to a site, a web page, and that has some danger.

Answer (score 2):

> i want to set it focused from start... But setting the focus does not work for me. I've tried all these methods

The proper method to use is the `requestFocusInWindow()` method. However, you can't request focus on a component unless the component is displayed in a visible GUI. So the basic code must be structured like:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
component.requestFocusInWindow();
```

It may not always be possible to structure your code that way and you want a component to request focus when it is created. In this case you can add an AncestorListener to the component so that it will request focus when it is displayed. Check out the [RequestFocusListener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) for code that does this for you.

Comment: this makes my program not load at all. I'll try using the RequestFocusListener but it looks complicated. Im a nub

Comment: @Azcrod: `"this makes my program not load at all"` -- then you're doing something wrong. If you need further help, clarify the problem that you're having with it and edit your question. +1 to this answer as it is (of course) the correct one.

Comment: @Azcrod, `I'll try using the RequestFocusListener but it looks complicated`, how is it complicated? You use the class as is and add one line of code to your program.